# Clear input fields after submitting AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, input

This is a password recovery form through HTML page that post data to PHP file via AJAX. Everything is okay with the code except once submitted and response recived, form input fields don't clear. I have been searching the web for the past 4 hours and found too many code lines to do so but none of them seems to work. plz help me in this matter :) have a good day.

```js
$(function() {
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////'Form ID' & 'Element Name' /////////////////////////////////////////
 // Get the form.
 var form = $('#emailform');

 // Get the messages div.
 var formMessages = $('#formresults');

 // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
 $(form).submit(function(e) {
  // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Serialize the form data.
  var formData = $(form).serialize();

  // Submit the form using AJAX.
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
  })
  
  .done(function(response) {
   
   // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
   $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
   $(formMessages).addClass('success');
   // Set the message text.
   $(formMessages).text(response);

   // Clear the form.
//   $('#email1').val('');
         //var email = $('input[name=#email]').val("");
   //document.getElementById("emailform").reset();
   //$('#emailform')[0].reset();
   //$('input:text').val('');
    //$('#emailform input[type=text]').val('');
      //setTimeout(function(){
            //$('input,textarea','#emailform').val(''); //clearing inputs
   //},1);


   
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
   // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
   $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
   $(formMessages).addClass('error');

   // Set the message text.
   if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
   } else {
    $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
   }
  });

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>AJAX Contact Form Demo</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page-wrapper">
   <h1>AJAX Contact Form Demo</h1>

   <div id="formresults"></div>
  
  <form id="emailform" name="emailform1" method="post" action="exa.php">
      <table align="center">
      <tr><td><div class="input-append"><input type="text" name="email" id="email1" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="email" maxlength="100" /><span class="add-on"><li class="icon-envelope"></li></span></div></td></tr>
      </table>
      <!-- <hr /> -->
      <center><input type="submit" name="Forget" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary Loading-btn" value="ٍSend" data-loading-text="Sending ..." /></center>
    </form>


 </div>
 
 <script src="ajax/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="ajax/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php   
// Get Access to data base

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $email = $_POST["email"];


    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($email) ) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(100);
        echo "BLABLABLA.";
        exit;
    }

    if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "BLABLABLA.";
        exit;
    }

    if (@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` WHERE `email`='$email'")) < 1) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(300);
        echo "BLABLABLA.";
        exit;
    }

            $row_user = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `email`='$email'"));
            ////////////////////////////
            $password = $row_user['pass'];
            $to = $row_user['email'];
            $subject = "Your Recovered Password";
            $message = "Please use this password to login: " . $password;
            $headers = "From : XXX@XXX.XXX";


    // Send the email.
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "BLABLABLA.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "BLABLABLA.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(600);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("emailform").reset();

Comment: @WebCode.ie didn't work :(

Comment: You're doing something wrong so. The code above will 100% clear out all populated form elements in the form.

Comment: @WebCode.ie this is what drives me mad. it works for everyone else but not me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `.reset()` function on the form element which will clear all input fields.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, just removed         http_response_code() 
for all if statments .

Thx all for your help. I can sleep now knowing my day is not wasted :)